# Proof that $u \in L^{\infty}(R)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $u \in C^{1}(R)$ and $u,u^{'} \in L^{2}(R)$. Proof that $u \in L^{\infty}(R)$.

Recently I got such a problem on the exam, it became interesting how it can be solved.

I realized that we need to estimate the norm $\|u\|_{\infty}$ from above using the norm $\|u\|_{2}$ and $\|u^{'}\|_{2}$

I try to use that
$$
\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u(x)^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty \text{  and } \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (u(x)^{'})^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty  
$$
But i don't understand how to use $u \in C^{1}(R)$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I tried to correct my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|u^2(x)-u^2(0)|=\left|\int_0^x(u^2)'(x)dx\right|=2\left|\int_0^xu(x)u'(x)dx\right|\leq 2|(u,u')_{L^2}|\leq 2\|u\|_2\|u'\|_2$$